# linq query : let with include statement

Tags: c#, linq, include, let

When I execute this request

```
var req = (from A in _context.STUDENT.Include("RESULT")
                   select A).ToList();
```

I have the expected result : For each STUDENT I have a number of RESULTs

but when I add a **let** statement like below, for each student I have 0 RESULT

```
var req = (from A in _context.STUDENT.Include("RESULT")
                   let b = 1
                   select A).ToList();
```

I'm I doing something wrong or is it a known issue or something ?

Comment: Well, in theory the `let` is a no-op, as you never use `b` for anything.  (Note that the first query also performs an identity select, which doesn't do anything productive.)  I guess your use of it is confusing the query provider somehow.  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: My real query is more complex. and I use the variable inside the let statement in the where clause. But for simplifying, I used this mock query as an example.

Comment: Don't you think the where clause is an important piece of information to add? It is likely that the where clause is the cause of returning 0 results, not just the inclusion of a let statement as your example suggests.

Comment: But I tested the query above and it didn't return result that should be returned

Comment: What linq provider are you using? You might want to tag your question with entity framework, etc., since they will operate differently. I can't imagine this being a linq-to-objects issue.

Comment: I'm using entity framework 6. I'm querying SQL server (I'm not using a custom provider or anything)

Comment: Have you tried this in LinqPad or profiled it to see what query is actually being generated? Might provide some clues.

Comment: I tested the queries with SQL profiler. The one without let execute a SQL query with a sub SQL query for the second entity (as it should). The one with let execute only a query with the STUDENT entity

Comment: "let" shouldn't modify the behaviour at all.. so maybe it's something else that you have on your query? Could you add the whole query? maybe that way we can understand why it is happening..

Answer (score 0):

A `let` statement that is not used should have no impact on your query.

To be sure, turn logging on and see for yourself in the console output that the generated TSQL is identical for both queries:

```
myContext.Log = Console.Out;
```